# Continue using node after parallel runs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After running tests in parallel, I need to immediately send out notifications.  Currently, the parallel nodes are ran then node is given up and the send notifications sometimes waits for next available node.

```
// List of tasks, one for each marker/label type.
def farmTasks = ['ac', 'dc']

// Create a number of agent tasks that matches the marker/label type.
// Deploys the image to the board, then checks out the code on the agent and
// runs the tests against the board.
timestamps {
    stage('Test') {
        def test_tasks = [:]
        for (int i = 0; i < farmTasks.size(); i++) {
            String farmTask = farmTasks[i]
            test_tasks["${farmTask}"] = {
                node("linux && ${farmTask}") {
                    stage("${farmTask}: checkout on ${NODE_NAME}") {
                        // Checkout without clean
                        doCheckout(false)

                    }
                    stage("${farmTask} tests") {
                        <code>
                    }
                 } // end of node
             } // end of test_tasks
         } // end of for
         parallel test_tasks
         node('linux') {
             sendMyNotifications();
         }
    } // end of Test stage
} // end of timestamps
```

Comment: Afaik you can allocate nodes while inside a node block already.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this code seems totally fine. I'm yet to understand how the notification needs to wait for a node (do you have more pipelines that use these agents? are there multiple instances of this pipeline running concurrently?), however the workaround to this issue is simple:

Set up another agent (it can reside on machines that already host existing agents) and give it a unique label (e.g. `notifications`) so its sole use will be to send notifications.

It's not perfect because you get a single point of failure, but it help remedy the situation while you figure out what causes the "real" agents to be unavailable after the parallel steps.